# Is there a generic representation of date using Epoch? Ticks vs milliseconds since Epoch

Tags: c#, .net, api, datetime, epoch

I am building an API that needs a date and I want to represent it using the Epoch.

Since I am developing in C# in .NET the ticks is an easy representation  (100 nanosecods).
However, I need also to cater to implementors of the API in other programming languages.

Is the concept of Ticks used other than in C#?  Should I go back to milliseconds since Epoch so the API is not designed too much with a .net flavor?

I know how to do the conversions, but I am looking for what makes more sense. My goal is to make the representation of dates easy for any programmer in all languages that may implement this API.

Thanks,

Comment: What's wrong with ISO 8601? :)

Comment: [ISO-8601-2004](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=40874)

Comment: Intentionally incorporating the Unix Millennium Bug into your design is rather unwise.  Those 26 years zip by in a hurry.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y2038

Comment: The bug only applies if you are representing the number with 32 bits which would be very unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you choose to use XML in your API or not, the standard defined in the [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) is a pretty safe bet.  See section 3.2.7, advising a specific version of one of the many ISO-8601 formats.